# FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1

Tags: mysql, android, android-studio, jdbc

Estoy trabajando con jdbc para conectar a base de datos mysql con android studio pero cuando ejecuto el programa y quiero hacer un registro de usuario la app se detiene y me marca en el logcat un error enorme que comienza con FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1.

Estuve leyendo y vi mucha gente que decía que los permisos de red pero yo ya puse el permission internet, no es eso y ya me quede sin ideas.

Este es el código de coneccion a base:

```
package com.example.metrofood;

import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.util.Log;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class ConectionClass
{
    String classs = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
    String url = "jdbc:mysql://ip/metrofood";
    String un = "root";
    String pass = "";

    @SuppressLint("NewApi")
    public Connection CONN() {
        StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder()
                .permitAll().build();
        StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
        Connection conn = null;
        String ConnURL = null;
        try {

            Class.forName(classs);

            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, un, pass);


            conn = DriverManager.getConnection(ConnURL);
        } catch (SQLException se) {
            Log.e("ERRO", se.getMessage());
        } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("ERRO", e.getMessage());
        }
        return conn;
    }

}
```

Y este el código de la actividad de registro

```
package com.example.metrofood;


import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.ActivityInfo;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.transition.Explode;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.Statement;


public class SignUp extends AppCompatActivity {

    EditText txt_User,txt_Pass,txt_ConfPass,txt_Email;
    Button sig;
    ConectionClass conectionClass;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);
        this.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT);

        txt_User=findViewById(R.id.txt_User);
        txt_Pass=findViewById(R.id.txt_Pass);
        txt_ConfPass=findViewById(R.id.txt_ConfPass);
        txt_Email=findViewById(R.id.txt_Email);

        conectionClass = new ConectionClass();

        Explode explode = new Explode();
        explode.setDuration(500);
        getWindow().setEnterTransition(explode);
        sig = findViewById(R.id.btn_Next);

        sig.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Register register = new Register();
                register.execute("");

                startActivity(new Intent(SignUp.this, Data.class));
            }
        });
    }

    public class Register extends AsyncTask<String,String,String>
    {
        String nombreUsu = txt_User.getText().toString();
        String passUsu = txt_Pass.getText().toString();
        String emailUsu = txt_Email.getText().toString();
        String z="";
        boolean isSuccess=false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

        }

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {

            if(nombreUsu.trim().equals("")|| emailUsu.trim().equals("") ||passUsu.trim().equals(""))
                z = "Please enter all fields correctamente";
            else
            {
                try {
                    Connection con = conectionClass.CONN();
                    if (con == null) {
                        z = "Please check your internet connection";
                    } else {

                        String query="insert into usuario values('"+nombreUsu+"','"+emailUsu+"','"+passUsu+"','4')";

                        Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                        stmt.executeUpdate(query);

                        z = "Register successfull";
                        isSuccess=true;


                    }
                }
                catch (Exception ex)
                {
                    isSuccess = false;
                    z = "Exceptions"+ex;
                }
            }
            return z;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(String s) {

            Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),""+z, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();


            if(isSuccess) {
                startActivity(new Intent(SignUp.this,Data.class));

            }

        }
    }

}
```

Por ultimo este es el error que me muestra a la hora de ejecutar la aplicacion:

```
> FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
    Process: com.example.metrofood, PID: 16471
    java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
        at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:304)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.finishCompletion(FutureTask.java:355)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:222)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:242)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
     Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError
        at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.isConnectionStringSupported(ConnectionUrlParser.java:148)
        at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrl.acceptsUrl(ConnectionUrl.java:258)
        at com.mysql.cj.jdbc.NonRegisteringDriver.connect(NonRegisteringDriver.java:187)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:179)
        at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:213)
        at com.example.metrofood.ConectionClass.CONN(ConectionClass.java:29)
        at com.example.metrofood.SignUp$Register.doInBackground(SignUp.java:76)
        at com.example.metrofood.SignUp$Register.doInBackground(SignUp.java:55)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:292)
        at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
        at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:231) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1112) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:587) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818) 
     Caused by: java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error in regexp pattern near index 4:
    (?<scheme>[\w:%]+)\s*(?://(?<authority>[^/?#]*))?\s*(?:/(?!\s*/)(?<path>[^?#]*))?(?:\?(?!\s*\?)(?<query>[^#]*))?(?:\s*#(?<fragment>.*))?
        ^
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compileImpl(Native Method)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:411)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.<init>(Pattern.java:394)
        at java.util.regex.Pattern.compile(Pattern.java:381)
        at com.mysql.cj.conf.ConnectionUrlParser.<clinit>(ConnectionUrlParser.java:89)
            ... 14 more
```

Agradeceria su ayuda, en serio me estoy martirizando con esa app.

Comment: Te sugiero cambies lo que estás mostrando para que no aparezca la I.P. a la que te conectas.  Estás dando mucho terreno a los hackers o gente osciosa.

Comment: Listo, gracias.

Comment: Estás enfocado una solución errónea. Realmente Android no soporta MySQL internamente (aunque me parece que hay formas de hacerlo funcionar, casi a la mala e invirtiendo tiempo y recursos para un funcionamiento siempre cuestionable). Si quieres una base de datos interna en la App deberías usar SQLite y programar además un ContentProvider. Si quieres usar una BD MySQL esta debería estar remotamente y programar un servicio REST o una API a la cual le pidas los datos vía protocolo `http`. Querer meter tu BD MySQL dentro de la app es una pésima idea, porque Android no está pensado para eso.

Answer (score 0):

Recientemente nos hemos topado con este mismo problema, y en nuestro caso se debía a que la API de nuestro emulador era la versión 24 y no el 30. Descargando la API nuestro problema se arreglo.

Espero que te sirva, un saludo!

Comment: Tu respuesta podría mejorarse con información de apoyo adicional. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir más detalles, como citas o documentación, para que otros puedan confirmar que tu respuesta es correcta. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).